# Meaning of "I shut my tongue against my fly"

Tags: meaning, elizabeth-barrett-browning, aurora-leigh

From [Aurora Leigh](http://digital.library.upenn.edu/women/barrett/aurora/aurora.html#1):

> Poor child! I would have mended it with gold,
>   Until it gleamed like St. Sophia's dome
>   When all the faithful troop to morning prayer:
>   But he, he nipped the bud of such a thought
>   With that cold Leigh look which I fancied once,
>   And broke in, 'Henceforth she was called his wife.
>   'His wife required no succour: he was bound
>   'To Florence, to resume this broken bond:
>   'Enough so. Both were happy, he and Howe,
>   'To acquit me of the heaviest charge of all–'
>   –**At which I shut my tongue against my fly**
>   And struck him; 'Would he carry,–he was just,–
>   'A letter from me to Aurora Leigh,
>   'And ratify from his authentic mouth
>   'My answer to her accusation?'–'Yes,
>   'If such a letter were prepared in time.'
>   –He's just, your cousin,–ay, abhorrently.

What does this mean? Is it some saying or proverb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [first edition of the poem](https://archive.org/details/aurora00leighbrowrich/page/372) (Chapman & Hall, London, 1857) has *shot*, not *shut*:

> –At which I shot my tongue against my fly
> And struck him;

Subsequent editions by Chapman & Hall also have *shot*; the Internet Archive has the [third (1857)](https://archive.org/details/auroraleighapoe01browgoog/page/n381) and [fifth (1860)](https://archive.org/details/auroraleighapoe00browgoog/page/n374) editions. It was in the early U.S. editions, for example [C. S. Francis & Co., New York (1857)](https://archive.org/details/auroraleigh00brow/page/338) that the word was changed to *shut*.

Almost certainly *shut* is a misprint, because the change makes nonsense of the line, while the original version is quite clear: it is a metaphor in which the writer  of the letter (Lady Waldemar) imagines herself a frog shooting out her tongue at a fly and striking it (‘him’). In the metaphor the fly stands for Romney Leigh, whom she has caught in her trap.